# android - AsyncTask being cancelled for some reason

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, task, handler

I have an AsyncTask class in android which I use for all kinds of requests from  a server - **improtant to point out that my requests are not working in parallel**, every request loads the data to the activity and after it loads the data -> the user can browse to another activity which sends another request.

I also have a **TaskCanceler** which is responsible to **cancel** the AsyncTask if it takes more than 8 seconds.

**The problem -**

For some reason, when I open the app and browse between, lets say, 5-6 activities, could be less or  more,
(each Activity sends a request to the server -> waits for respond -> populate the Activity with data), at some point I go to an Activity and it starts to load the data, and then, **after about 1 second**, I see the `OnCancelled()` Error message `("no connection to server!")`.

This means that the `OnCancelled()` has been called - and the **TaskCenceler** should only call it after **8 seconds!**.

I checked, and the server answers all the requests - but the android app just "doesn't wait" for one of the requests out of nowhere.

Why is it happening? its not specific to an Activity, each time it happens on a different one. why all of the sudden the **TaskCenceler** doesn't wait to full 8 seconds?

**My AsyncTask:**

```
private class executeRequest extends AsyncTask<HttpRequest, Void, Integer> {

    private ResponseListener listener;

    public executeRequest(ResponseListener responseListener) {
        listener = responseListener; 
        // Listener in the Activity to respond to Error/Success 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        handleCancelled();
        // if more than 8 seconds passed
    }

    private void handleCancelled() {
        if (taskCanceler != null && handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(taskCanceler);
        }
        listener.onError("no connection to server!");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(HttpRequest... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpRequest request = params[0];
        int responseCode = -1;
        HttpResponse response;
        responseResult = "";
        response = httpClient.execute((HttpUriRequest) request);
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        responseResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),
                    HTTP.UTF_8);
        return responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
          // handle response
    }
}
```

**TaskCanceller:**

```
public class TaskCanceler implements Runnable {
    public executeRequest task;

    public TaskCanceler() {
    }

    public void setTask(executeRequest task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (task != null)
            if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                task.onCancelled();
            }
    }
}
```

**This is how I start all of my Tasks:**

```
// Setting up the Handler  and the TaskCanceler
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TaskCanceler taskCanceler = new TaskCanceler();

task = new executeRequest(responseListener, type);
taskCanceler.setTask(task);
handler.postDelayed(taskCanceler, 8 * 1000); // cancel after 8 seconds
task.execute(refuseJoinRide);
```

Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the log that you are getting is actually not from the task that you recently started. It could be from other activity that you started earlier.

Comment: You should also use AsyncTask#cancel(boolean) instead of onCancelled() when cancelling your task.